# Here map integration in react-native mobile app

Tags: react-native, here-api

I am trying to implement heremap api in react-native project.While searching got https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-heremaps .But there is no proper documents to use this library. I am new to react-native. Please give me some suggestions to implement this.

Comment: What do you want to use from HERE? I once needed a route calculation API and I developed it with HERE, so if you need only route calculation with here and then displaying it in react native I can help you

Comment: I want to show markers and draw polyline with heremap. Can you help me out to do this.

Comment: Sure, let me write an answer for you.

Answer (score 13):

*! if you don't use expo please comment and I'll change the answer a bit !*

First of all, as you probably know you need to make an account at [HERE Developer webiste](https://developer.here.com/).

After you have made an account, you have to create a project(you can get a Freemium plan for free and it has plenty of requests available for free, upgrade if you need more). After that you need to "Generate App" for REST & XYZ HUB API/CLI at your project page. With that, you will recieve APP ID and APP CODE. With all this, HERE Developer Account setup is complete.

Lets jump to React Native now.

First of all you need to install a npm package called `react-native-maps` which we will use to display data that HERE provides. You can see installation instructions [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps).

After this, lets assume you have already created a component that will show the map. You need to import this:

```
import { Marker, Polyline } from 'react-native-maps'
import { MapView } from 'expo'
```

With that we have our map almost ready.

I will use `axios` in this example but you can use `fetch` to make requests to HERE if you want.

So we import axios(if you never worked with it you can learn more about it [here](https://github.com/axios/axios)):

```
import axios from 'axios'
```

Now, you should have coordinates of those two locations ready in a state or somewhere, and it should look something like this:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        startingLocation: {
            latitude: "xx.x",
            longitude: "yy.y",
        },
        finishLocation: {
           latitude: "xx.x",
           longitude: "yy.y",
        }
    }
}
```

With "xx.x" and "yy.y" being actual coordinates you want.

So now when you have coordinates of start and finish location you can make a request to you HERE API project. It's as easy as this(I got this api from [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/request-a-simple-route.html)):

```js
// I will create a function which will call this, you can call it whenever you want
_getRoute = () => {
    // we are using parseFloat() because HERE API expects a float
    let from_lat = parseFloat(this.state.startingLocation.latitude)
    let from_long = parseFloat(this.state.startingLocation.longitude)
    let to_lat = parseFloat(this.state.finishLocation.latitude)
    let to_long = parseFloat(this.state.finishLocation.longitude)
    // we will save all Polyline coordinates in this array
    let route_coordinates = []
    axios.get(`https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_id=PUT_YOUR_APP_ID_HERE&app_code=PUT_YOUR_APP_CODE_HERE&waypoint0=geo!${from_lat},${from_long}&waypoint1=geo!${to_lat},${to_long}&mode=fastest;bicycle;traffic:disabled&legAttributes=shape`).then(res => {
        // here we are getting all route coordinates from API response
        res.data.response.route[0].leg[0].shape.map(m => {
            // here we are getting latitude and longitude in seperate variables because HERE sends it together, but we
            // need it seperate for <Polyline/>
            let latlong = m.split(',');
            let latitude = parseFloat(latlong[0]);
            let longitude = parseFloat(latlong[1]);
            routeCoordinates.push({latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude});
        }
        this.setState({
            routeForMap: routeCoordinates,
            // here we can access route summary which will show us how long does it take to pass the route, distance etc.
            summary: res.data.response.route[0].summary,
            // NOTE just add this 'isLoading' field now, I'll explain it later
            isLoading: false,
        })
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
}
```

**NOTE** There are few things to note here. First is that you have to replace APP ID and APP CODE with acutal APP ID and APP CODE from your HERE project.
Second note that I added `&legAttributes=shape` at the end of the request URL but it is not in the documentation. I put it there so Polyline coordinates acutally have a correct shape, if you don't put it, it will just respond with coordinates of road turns and that polyline will go over buildings and stuff, it will just look bad.

OK. So now we have coordinates to make a Polyline, let's do that.

```
<MapView>
  <Polyline coordinates={this.state.routeForMap} strokeWidth={7} strokeColor="red" geodesic={true}/>
  <Marker coordinate={{latitude: this.state.startingLocation.latitude, longitude: this.state.startingLocation.longitude}} title="Starting location"/>
  <Marker coordinate={{latitude: this.state.finishLocation.latitude, longitude: this.state.finishLocation.longitude}} title="Finishlocation"/>
</MapView>
```

Explanation:
Polyline.coordinates will map through all of the coordinates that we have provided and draw a Polyline. strokeWidth is just how thick you want your line to be, and strokeColor is obviously color of a line.

Now, you should add a `region` to your MapView component to let it know what is the initial region you want to show on the map. So I suggest you to do something like this:

In state, define a region field and make it the same coordinates as starting location, and then set delta to make a bit larger view.

```js
// so in state just add this
region: {
  latitude: parseFloat("xx.x"),
  longitude: parseFloat("yy.y"),
  latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
  longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
}
```

And now, add `region={this.state.region}` to MapView.

You would be done now, but let's make sure this works every time. You need to make sure that HERE API request is complete before the map renders. I would do it like this:

```js
// in your state define field to control if loading is finished
isLoading: true,
```

Now, you would call the function `_getRoute()` we made before in componendDidMount() lifecycle function provided by React Native. Like this:

```js
componentDidMount() {
  // when this function is finished, we will set isLoading state to false to let program know that API request has finished and now we can render the map
  this._getRoute()
}
```

So finally a final step is to control `isLoading` in your render() function:

```js
render() {
  if(this.state.isLoading) {
    return (
      <Text>Loading...(you could also use <ActivityIndicator/> or what ever you want to show while loading the request)</Text>
    )
  } else {
    // just put everything we already did here + stuff you already have
  }
}
```

So here it is. I tried to make it as detailed as possible to make it easy for you and other people that will need help with this.

Don't ever hesitate to ask me anything if something is unclear or it's not working or you need more help! I'm always happy to help :D

Comment: to implement 'react-native-maps' google key is needed? Because I don't want to use google map or key. How I will show here map in background.

Comment: You dont need a google key, just ignore it and make a request to HERE, and then you will display that data on map view.

Comment: while I am using expo map and react-native maps together it's giving me " Tried to register two views with the same name AIRMap" error. why??

Comment: Do you have 2 same imports from 'expo' and from 'react-native-maps'? It would be better if you could paste me here your imports.

Comment: No I don't have 2 mapview imports. I did same way like you did.
import { Marker, Polyline } from 'react-native-maps'
import { MapView } from 'expo'

Comment: Hello, @crodev thank u for this amazing explanation but I have some questions, as u say we will use RN-maps so when setup it we add a Google maps key to the Androidmanifaets file to render it so with HERE API how can I handle it? The second question I don't use Expo so ur answer will help me? or there are a few things should I change? Thanks in advance

Comment: And i just try and everything works well  but when I ignore my google maps api key I got an error when rendering the map "API key not found in AndroidManifest.xml file" 
FYI I import MapView from react-native-maps, not Expo!

Comment: Hello @DevAS, I was also getting same error. Without google api key only debug apk will work. When we'll create signed apk then it'll ask for google api key.

Comment: Hi @Ana  Yeah, Google does not support my client visa card i don't know how to solve it yet

Comment: I have loaded here map in react native webview using Leaflet javascript library.

Comment: Sorry for not replying to your comments. I will try to solve the issues this week. Havent been on the site lately.

Comment: @DevAS are you getting a fatal error where app does not work at all, or just a yellow warning?

Comment: @crodev I just think your answer work without using Google Maps key so I got the Error that's saying I don't have a map key so I just add a key and it works fine.

Comment: Sorry, I am confused. Why are you using react-native-maps? It looks like the OP wants to use the HEREMaps SDK.