# Here map integration using React native

Tags: javascript, react-native, here-api, react-native-maps

I've been trying to integrate Here Maps on my react native app, I followed this "tutorial"
but with no success. I think the tutorial is for Expo only.

[Here map integration in react-native mobile app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58049010/here-map-integration-in-react-native-mobile-app/58068474#58068474)

And here is the code I wrote

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
    SafeAreaView,
    ScrollView,
    StatusBar,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    useColorScheme,
    View,
    TextInput
  } from 'react-native';

import MapView,{Polyline, Marker}from 'react-native-maps';
import axios from 'axios'


class ShowMap extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            startingLocation: {
                latitude: "37.025",
                longitude: "-122.023",
            },
            finishLocation: {
               latitude: "37.78825",
               longitude: "-122.4324",
            },
            region: {
                latitude: parseFloat("37.025"),
                longitude: parseFloat("-122.023"),
                latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
                longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
              },
              isLoading: true
        }
    }
            
    _getRoute = () => {
        let from_lat = parseFloat(this.state.startingLocation.latitude)
        let from_long = parseFloat(this.state.startingLocation.longitude)
        let to_lat = parseFloat(this.state.finishLocation.latitude)
        let to_long = parseFloat(this.state.finishLocation.longitude)
        let route_coordinates = []
        axios.get(`https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?apiKey={api_key_here}&waypoint0=geo!${from_lat},${from_long}&waypoint1=geo!${to_lat},${to_long}&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled`).then(res => {
            // here we are getting all route coordinates from API response
            res.data.response.route[0].leg[0].shape.map(m => {
                // here we are getting latitude and longitude in seperate variables because HERE sends it together, but we
                // need it seperate for <Polyline/>
                let latlong = m.split(',');
                let latitude = parseFloat(latlong[0]);
                console.log(latitude);
                
                let longitude = parseFloat(latlong[1]);
                console.log(longitude);

                routeCoordinates.push({latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude});
            })
            this.setState({
                routeForMap: routeCoordinates,
                // here we can access route summary which will show us how long does it take to pass the route, distance etc.
                summary: res.data.response.route[0].summary,
                // NOTE just add this 'isLoading' field now, I'll explain it later
                isLoading: false,
            })

        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // when this function is finished, we will set isLoading state to false to let program know that API request has finished and now we can render the map
        this._getRoute()
      }
    
    render() {
        if(this.state.isLoading) {
            return (
              <Text>Loading...(you could also use or what ever you want to show while loading the request)</Text>
            )
          } else{
        return (
<MapView region={this.state.region}>
  <Polyline coordinates={this.state.routeForMap} strokeWidth={7} strokeColor="red" geodesic={true}/>
  <Marker coordinate={{latitude: parseFloat(this.state.startingLocation.latitude), longitude: parseFloat(this.state.startingLocation.longitude)}} title="Starting location"/>
  <Marker coordinate={{latitude: parseFloat(this.state.finishLocation.latitude), longitude: parseFloat(this.state.finishLocation.longitude)}} title="Finishlocation"/>
</MapView>
        );
      }
    }


}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
      height: 400,
      width: 400,
      justifyContent: 'flex-end',
      alignItems: 'center',
    },
    map: {
      ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    },
   });

   export default ShowMap;
```

and here is the result I get
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xoU4.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `&legAttributes=shape` at the end of your Axios request URL.

I assume that `res.data.response.route[0].leg[0].shape` gives an error since there is no shape array since you didn't set that in the request URL and then it goes to catch that error in Axios. Which in the end never sets `isLoading` to false.

In the end, your Axios get should look like this:

```js
axios.get(`https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?apiKey={api_key_here}&waypoint0=geo!${from_lat},${from_long}&waypoint1=geo!${to_lat},${to_long}&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled&legAttributes=shape`).then(res => {
```

Let me know if it still doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer,
I have made the changes you mentioned in your answer.
But after that I had an error  [ReferenceError: Can't find variable: routeCoordinates]
in the code you wrote in the solution you wrote routeCoordinates.push({latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude}); while you have declared     let route_coordinates = []

so I changed     let route_coordinates = [] to routeCoordinates
Now ALMOST everything works fine, since I no longer have errors in the console, but the only problem that I have now is that the map is showing gray

Comment: Update on my last comment : 
The map showed in gray since I forgot to enable Google Maps SDK, you need to enable it , and wait for like 5 minutes, and the map will show up fine

Comment: Hello I tried your suggestion. But it gives me an axios error 403, it says that credentials do not authorize access

https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?{API_KEY_CODE}&waypoint0=geo!${origin.latitude},${origin.longitude}&waypoint1=geo!${origin.latitude},${origin.longitude}&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled&legAttributes=shape

Comment: Did you create an API key from the HERE developer account and paste it to the URL?

Answer (score 0):

You are using MapView only for expo. Try to use it for React native.

Refer following link for MapView in React native:

[React Native MapView](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps)

Comment: I'm already using Map View for react native import MapView,{Polyline, Marker}from 'react-native-maps';