# Integrating HERE Indoor Map into React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, here-api

I am wondering if it is possible to integrate HERE Indoor Maps into React Native. With all the research I have done, it seems the only way to render a here indoor map is to create native modules for both Android and iOS. I have never done anything like this and it seems very complex.

Would it be possible to make some sort of wrapper and use the [Indoor Maps for JS](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.30.16/dev_guide/topics/indoor-maps.html) and integrate that into a React Native application?

I applogize I do not have any code to share, this is just purley research. I would greatly apreaciate any direction or input.

Comment: You can check this answer for HERE Indoor Map with React Naive App 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58049010/here-map-integration-in-react-native-mobile-app/58068474#58068474
Maybe It helps

Answer (score 2):

HERE does not support React Native Officially .. If you need to write your application in React native you will have to write the bindings by yourself.

Now if you are using the Here Indoor JS API then I think you should consider implementing it with a webview container.